# Call Web API to Update Custom Field on Post Save in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to grab some data from a web API and stick it in a custom field when the user hits update in Wordpress. I have a js file that correctly gets the API data and am enqueueing the script with the code below. The problem is timing. The fetch call obviously comes in too late and the post is saved before I can add it to the custom field.  Not sure how to set this up?

```
if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'speakers' ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'test', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js?v=111', 'jquery', '', true );
    }
}
```

Plus - I have to make the API call in the browser, not server side.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [pre_post_update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/) action to process your API data before the save, this will work only for updating posts, not creating.

```
function do_something_before_updating_post($post_id, $post_data) {
 // Run your API
}

add_action('pre_post_update', 'do_something_before_updating_post', 10, 2);
```

Comment: I need to make the API call in the browser (javascript).  I can't make the call on the server (PHP).  Possible to do that from this hook?  Not sure how I would do that...

Comment: More info: The API I need to call before saving the post has some restrictions on being called from the server, that's why the call needs to come from the browser when user is updating the post. I can use something like pre_post_update but the code which needs to make the web API call (to get the value for the field) needs to happen in JS not PHP. I'm just not sure how to set that up and make sure the timing works so that my API call returns before the post is saved.

Comment: So basically... - user presses "Update" button on a post - code stops the update - js code (in the browser running WP admin, not php on the server) gets information from a web API - code fills in a custom field on the post with the data returned from the API - once API returns and field is populated, now update the post.  So...  PHP then JS then PHP again once JS ascync API call returns.